# Class/event schedule calendar

Tags: php, datetime, matrix

This is a calendar to layout an array of events/classes (from an API) in calendar format:

> ```
>        Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
> time   event  |  event  |    event  |   event  | event  |   event  | event
> time   event  |  event  |    event  |   event  | event  |   event  | event
> time   event  |  event  |    event  |   event  | event  |   event  | event
> time   event  |  event  |    event  |   event  | event  |   event  | event
> time   event  |  event  |    event  |   event  | event  |   event  | event
> time   event  |  event  |    event  |   event  | event  |   event  | event
> ```

This is the function the array of events is fed to:

```php
<?php
function sortClassesByTimeThenDay($mz_classes = array()) {
    $mz_classesByTime = array();

    // Add top level value to each class to store day of week
    for($i=0;$i<count($mz_classes);$i++)
    {
        $mz_classes[$i]['day_num'] = '';
    }

    foreach($mz_classes as &$class)
    {
        /* Create a new array with a key for each time
        and corresponsing value an array of class details 
        for classes at that time. */ 
        $classTime = date_i18n("G.i", strtotime($class['StartDateTime'])); // for numerical sorting
        $display_time = (date_i18n("g:i a", strtotime($class['StartDateTime']))); 
        $classDay = date_i18n("l", strtotime($class['StartDateTime'])); // Weekday name
        $class['day_num'] = date_i18n("N", strtotime($class['StartDateTime'])); // Weekday num 1-7
        if(!empty($mz_classesByTime[$classTime])) {
            $mz_classesByTime[$classTime]['classes'] = array_merge($mz_classesByTime[$classTime]['classes'], array($class));
        } else {
            $mz_classesByTime[$classTime] = array('display_time' => $display_time, 
                                                    'classes' => array($class));
        }
    }
    /* Timeslot keys in new array are not time-sequenced so do so*/
    ksort($mz_classesByTime);
    foreach($mz_classesByTime as $scheduleTime => &$mz_classes)
    {
        /*
        $mz_classes is an array of all classes for given time
        Take each of the class arrays and order it by days 1-7
        */
        usort($mz_classes['classes'], function($a, $b) {
            if(date_i18n("N", strtotime($a['StartDateTime'])) == date_i18n("N", strtotime($b['StartDateTime']))) {
                return 0;
            }
            return $a['StartDateTime'] < $b['StartDateTime'] ? -1 : 1;
        }); 
        $mz_classes['classes'] = week_of_timeslot($mz_classes['classes'], 'day_num');
    }
    return $mz_classesByTime;
}

function week_of_timeslot($array, $indicator){
    /*
    Make a clean array with seven corresponding slots and populate 
    based on indicator (day) for each class. There may be more than
    one event for each day and empty arrays will represent empty time slots.
    */
    $seven_days = array_combine(range(1, 7), array(array(), array(), array(),
                                            array(), array(), array(), array()));
        foreach($seven_days as $key => $value){
            foreach ($array as $class) {
                    if ($class[$indicator] == $key){
                        array_push($seven_days[$key], $class);
                    }
                }
            }
    return $seven_days;
    }
?>
```

And using [HTML Table Class](http://www.dyn-web.com/php/table_class/), the calendar is displayed:

```php
<?php
$mz_days = sortClassesByTimeThenDay($mz_days);
$tbl = new HTML_Table('', 'mz-schedule-filter');
        $tbl->addTSection('thead');
        $tbl->addRow();
        // arguments: cell content, class, type (default is 'data' for td, pass 'header' for th)
        // can include associative array of optional additional attributes
        $tbl->addCell('', '', 'header');
        $tbl->addCell('Monday', '', 'header');
        $tbl->addCell('Tuesday', '', 'header');
        $tbl->addCell('Wednesday', '', 'header');
        $tbl->addCell('Thursday', '', 'header');
        $tbl->addCell('Friday', '', 'header');
        $tbl->addCell('Saturday', '', 'header');
        $tbl->addCell('Sunday', '', 'header');

$tbl->addTSection('tbody');
foreach($mz_days as $classDate => $mz_classes)
    {                   
        $tbl->addRow();
        $tbl->addCell($time_of_day, 'hidden', 'data');
        $tbl->addCell($mz_classes['display_time']);
        foreach($mz_classes['classes'] as $key => $classes)
        {
            if(empty($classes)){
                $class_details = '';
                }else{
                $class_details = '';
                $class_separator = (count($classes) > 1) ? '<hr/>' : '';
                foreach($classes as $class){
                        $className = $class['ClassDescription']['Name'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            $tbl->addCell($class_details, 'mz_description_holder');
        }//end foreach mz_classes
    }//end foreach mz_days
$return .= $tbl->display();
?>
```

I'd like input on styling, comments, syntax, and I'm especially interested in ways to reduce the number of loops being run in `sortClassesByTimeThenDay()`.

It seems like maybe `array_map` could be used to insert the ordered events into the seven day matrix/array or possibly `usort` and `week_of_timeslot` could be combined, but not sure how. At the moment I'm basking in the miracle that I made it work at all.

Answer (score 2):

#### Prefer `foreach` when possible

In this loop:

> ```
> for($i=0;$i<count($mz_classes);$i++)
> {
>     $mz_classes[$i]['day_num'] = '';
> }
> ```

The loop index is tedious, and distracting.
At a higher level,
your actual purpose is to initialize `'day_num'` in each element,
the array index is only there for technical reasons,
it's not really part of your logic.

A `foreach` loop without an index variable can help focus on your actual purpose:

```
foreach ($mz_classes as &$mz_class) {
    $mz_class['day_num'] = '';
}
```

The result is cleaner and shorter too, so overall better in many ways.

#### Avoid unnecessary operations + limit scope

In this code:

> ```
>     $display_time = (date_i18n("g:i a", strtotime($class['StartDateTime']))); 
>     $classDay = date_i18n("l", strtotime($class['StartDateTime'])); // Weekday name
>     $class['day_num'] = date_i18n("N", strtotime($class['StartDateTime'])); // Weekday num 1-7
>     if(!empty($mz_classesByTime[$classTime])) {
>         $mz_classesByTime[$classTime]['classes'] = array_merge($mz_classesByTime[$classTime]['classes'], array($class));
>     } else {
>         $mz_classesByTime[$classTime] = array('display_time' => $display_time, 
>                                                 'classes' => array($class));
>     }
> ```

`$classDay` is never used, so it shouldn't be there.

`$display_time` is only used in the `else` branch.
So it should be created there, for many reasons:

- Avoid an unnecessary operation when the `else` branch is not reached
- Declare variables close to where they are actually used
- Limit variables to the smallest possible scope: a weak reason in PHP, but a good habit nonetheless

#### Formatting

This writing style is too compact:

> ```
> for($i=0;$i<count($mz_classes);$i++)
> ```

It would be more readable to follow good spacing conventions in other languages, like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mz_classes); $i++)
```

Comment: `$class['day_num'] = date_i18n("N", strtotime($class['StartDateTime']));` seems to be working within `foreach($mz_classes as &$class)` now, although the reason I had created the `for` loop based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233169/php-adding-new-key-to-the-array-used-in-foreach above it it because it wasn't working previously. Obviously my understanding (and/or testing) is lacking here.

Comment: The trick is the `&`, to make the loop variable use references instead of values. Otherwise the original list wouldn't be updated, as the loop variable will be a copy instead of the real item in the array.

Comment: I actually know about passing by reference with the `&`, but it's certainly possible I wasn't doing it at the time of the "not working". At any rate, we may have removed an iteration here, which is exciting.